# I'm stuck to create rfid card in ios app and create .pkpass file then add into apple wallet using flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-wallet, pkpass

this is my code in this doesn't create an RFID card and pk pass I want to create an RFID/NFC card in my app and create a pk pass file and add it to the apple wallet I search several websites but I didn't find that error inside it.  if you face this kind of problems please help me

```
   

    final _saveCard = StreamBuilder(
      stream: bloc.savecardValid,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40,
          height: 50,
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text(
              'Save Card',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            onPressed: snapshot.hasData
                ? () {
                    var blocProviderCardWallet = BlocProvider(
                      bloc: bloc,
                      child: CardWallet(),
                    );
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => blocProviderCardWallet));
                  }
                : null,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Apps on iOS cannot add nfc cards without a special entitlement from Apple and even then there are restrictions on the supported protocols

Comment: I want to create a unique RFID/NFC card giving Uid and card name then i want create a pkpass file for that and I can add into apple  wallet that is my scene

Comment: You keep saying rfid/nfc but this isn't what pkpasses are. They are just graphical items. They can contain a QRCode or barcode and images and text. Regardless, you should read [ask] and explain your problem more clearly

Comment: I want to be able to open RFID/NFC controlled doors.
Most doors just use the UID of the card presented.
IOS Wallet can also send out a UID (for apple pay it uses randomized uids, so this is not useful).

Therefore I need an app that creates .pkpass files, so I can add the created files to apple wallet.
All it needs to do is send out a UID I define in the app

Comment: This is not something you can do with Apple Wallet. At WWDC 2021 Apple announced support for some access card support in Apple Wallet and I believe that the first products are now available in the market, but you need specific hardware in the reader and a specific entitlement from Apple. You cannot add arbitrary NFC "cards" to the Apple Wallet.

Comment: can I create pkpass file using flutter app for that

Comment: Not one that emulates an NFC card; That isn't something you can do in *any* language

Comment: Do you mean it is impossible and  how I create pass using flutter app

Comment: I mean it is possible to create a pass with a flutter app; Google search shows a few different plugins - [this is just one](https://github.com/vico-aguado/flutter_wallet).  What is impossible is for that pass to act as an NFC card.  Apple Wallet doesn't work that way.  Authorised banking apps can provide payment cards and apple has  announced plans for some vendors to support special access control cards in the wallet, but you can't just add an arbitrary NFC card